# How to get Downloads path in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the below code to get the path to Downloads folder:

```dart
final output = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
RegExp pathToDownloads = new RegExp(r'.+0\/');
final outputPath = '${pathToDownloads.stringMatch(output.path).toString()}Downloads';
```

The above code generates this string:
`/storage/emulated/0/Downloads`

But console says "No such file or directory". I created this path string because some answers on stack overflow mention that the above is the location of the downloads folder but it isn't. So what is the path to downloads folder on android and how to get access to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
The following example code write a text file to `Downloads` folder

Step 1: You can add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Step 2: Use package `ext_storage` https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage and Request permission with https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler 4.4.0

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  ext_storage: any
  permission_handler: 4.4.0
```

Step 4: Request permission

```
 void requestPermission() {  

//permission_handler 10.2.0
await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();

//permission_handler 4.4.0
//PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);

  }
```

Step 5: get `Downloads` folder with `ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`

```
String path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    String path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    print(path);
    File file = await File('$path/counter.txt');
    file.writeAsString('this is test');

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void requestPermission() {
    PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    requestPermission();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I downloaded the `ext_storage` package just to see which path it gets for the downloads folder and I found that it points to `Download`, in my original code, I was using `Downloads`, an extra 's' was causing the issue :) `PermissionHandler()` isn't working for me, I am getting the message it is undefined so I went to the page for this package and used this code which worked `if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {...}`

Comment: I use Permission Handler 4.4.0, you can see I mentioned in post, because 5.x has bug and in some case will not work.

Comment: when you use `permission_handler: ^5`. try `await Permission.storage.request()`

Answer (score 6):

You can get download path without any package. Try that:

```
Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
```

Comment: this only applies to android right?

Comment: @chitgoks yes, just Android